# Are items that disappear from Fallout: New Vegas companion inventories lost forever?

Tags: xbox-360, fallout-new-vegas

Twice now, I've completed a side quest in *Fallout: New Vegas*, received a unique weapon, given that weapon to one of my companions and then had the weapon disappear completely from the game. Is there a way to get these weapons back? I'm playing the 360 version, so console shenanigans won't work.

I have a theory about why this is happening, but I haven't been able to prove it. I'm guessing the weapon condition drops to zero while the companion is using it. When my own items break down in use, they just get grayed-out in the Pip-Boy screen, but they can still be repaired or transferred to a container. Maybe the companion inventories can't handle such unusable items?

Comment: Companion weapons don't degrade, so it isn't that.

Comment: @Less, are you sure about that? I've given companions items at full CND only to see them at 80% or so later on. Might have been armor, though.

Comment: Armor shouldn't degrade when used by companions either. Weapons *can* degrade if they're hit directly by weapons -  i.e. if your companion takes a shot to the gun, but that's it as far as I know.

Comment: it may be that the weapons were knocked out of youe companion's hands. as @Less says weapons can be attacked, and i've seem them get knocked out of enemy hands before.

Comment: @Xantec, that's true, but man, it'd be some coincidence for that to happen after the weapon reached zero CND and before my companion switched out for another weapon.

Comment: well, that is also assuming that they didn't toss the weapon when it reached 0%.

Comment: Just want to comment here that I have had weapons as well as a weapon upgrade (sniper suppressor) disappear. This was in my inventory, not my partner's inventory. It is definitely a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some behavior I just saw and explained in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11273/do-companions-weapons-degrade-in-fallout-new-vegas/11274#11274), I have a new theory. I'm thinking that the weapon did degrade to the point where it broke, my companion tossed it aside and I didn't realize it. So, somewhere in my game world, there are two broken unique weapons sitting out in a hallway or a field, with no way for me to find them other than dumb luck.

Here's a summary of that other answer so you don't have to click:

I gave my companion a weapon and got into a fight with several enemies who don't use that weapon type. During the battle, I heard my companion yell "I'm gonna need a new weapon!" After the battle, she didn't have that weapon anymore, and I found a weapon of that type on the ground with an empty CND gauge.

Answer (score 3):

I think this may be a bug.  I have Veronica and gave her the Q-35.  She was doing fine until I saw her shooting her stock 10mm at a giant radscorpion.  I look in her inventory, no Q-35.  I use a console code to give myself another one, and give it back to her (items are created with full CND).  She did not equip nor drop it, I checked her inventory again and... no Q-35.

I loaded from before I gave it back to her, generated another one and put it in her inventory, saw it sitting there before I closed it, transferred it back to me and her a couple times, and now it seems like it's staying there.  For now, anyway.

This is definitely sounding like a bug though, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3):

The poster who made the comment about the patch deletion only working on the PC was wrong, fortunately for those of us on the XBox 360 (and hopefully for you PS3 users as well).  The solution for me ended up being very simple but I will list step by step directions to clear any confusion.

(NOTE: If you rely on your auto-save or your auto-save is your most recent save you would like to play from, I recommend saving a new manual file before attempting the steps below.)

1. Exit to the XBox dashboard.
2. Go to the "My XBox" menu and scroll all the way to the right and select "System Settings".
3. Select "Memory".
4. Choose the appropriate Storage Device, likely your "Hard Drive".
5. Select "Games".
6. Find "Fallout: New Vegas" and select it.
7. Find the file labeled "Fallout New Vegas Title Update #5 (the number on yours could be higher if you are reading this after another update, or lower if you somehow have an old update) and DELETE it (do NOT move it, as the game will still detect it).
8. Launch Fallout New Vegas as you normally would.  A guide window will immediately open once the game launches and will ask if you want to apply the available update for the game.  IMPORTANT: Choose "Cancel".
9. Load your desired save file (I believe you may need to load one from outside the casino or other place that confiscate your weapons).
10. Upon loading, you may need to exchange some items with your companions to balance weight as some item weights were different before the patch.  Make sure your companions have the room they will need to hold all the weapons you had them carrying beforehand.
11. Fast travel to the location where your weapons were lost and save a new file at the door (just a precautionary measure that should always be taken when doing this sort of thing).
12. Enter the building and allow the guard to take all your weapons.
13. Exit the building.  Your companions should now have all the weapons they had before they were stolen the first time.
14. Save a new file.
15. Exit to dashboard.
16. Start the game back up again.
17. This time, allow the patch to be applied.
18. Load your newly saved game as normal, but this time, be careful to dismiss companions or take all their weapons and only let them hold your non-weapons (although this could possibly allow the other similar bug to occur where Companion "Unique" weapons disappear) before entering buildings like the casinos.

If the problem occurs again, you should be able to repeat the steps above to resolve it again, however, prevention is the best medicine.

Comment: After re-reading the OP and other comments, I realized that while my answer above applies to a few comments, it might not necessarily apply to the OP.  If someone would be so kind as to repost my directions into the applicable post, and send me a link, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Can't help but clarify. It is a bug. Sometimes weapons get knocked out of their hands and disappear. Had it happen while fighting deathclaws. The chainsaw dropped out of Veronicas hands and rolled down a hill and I just turned my back and it was nowhere to be found.

Comment: Don't think it's being knocked out of their hands. I've lost a long list of items, including: all-American, q-35, 10mm pistol, 2 silenced .22 smg's, several sniper rifles, 2 12.7mm smg's, and probably much more. These couldn't all have been shot out of their hands, and furthermore, I never gave Boone ammo for any of them, and even if I did, ED-E wouldn't be able to equip them, and I have lost several that were in his inventory too.

Answer (score 0):

Is this by chance happening when you visit Casinos?

There are a few bugs that seem to be associated with companion inventories, and areas where your weapons are stripped, such as Casinos and The Fort. The easiest workaround is to just have your companions wait outside.

Comment: No, this is out in the wasteland. I'll look over, and my companion will be using the weapon I provided, and five minutes later the same companion will be empty-handed.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly, the items are lost forever on a 360.

Here's the list of bugs for Fallout:New Vegas.  Everyone I know that played this game (a whole 6 people!) encountered at least one of these:
http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_bugs

Answer (score -2):

First i deleted my 1.06 game patch in the "game data utility" folder.

I then started the game and installed the game data, but i *didn't* install the 1.06 update. Instead, when it asked me if i wanted to install 1.06, i clicked Cancel so that it would stay at 1.0. I then loaded my save file.

Once i was on the strip, i entered Gomorrah, left it, then checked my companions' inventories and all of my weapons etc. were back!

I finally deleted my DLC and reinstated it (you don't actually need to do this: the dlc will work even in version 1.0), i reinstated the 1.06 update and its working great!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately, your suggestion is not applicable in this case because the original poster is playing the Xbox 360 version, and as such does not have access to options available to PC gamers.