# Do companions' weapons degrade in Fallout: New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

It was claimed in [this comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11261/#comment-15556) that companions' weapons don't degrade in *Fallout: New Vegas*. Is that true? What about companions' armor? Does the difficulty of the game influence this? What about hardcore mode?

This question is *not* about companions' default items that can't be taken away. It's about items that you add to your companions' inventory manually.

Answer (score 16):

This was changed several patches ago and I never updated my answer.

As of a patch some time ago, companions' weapons degrade per attack at the same rate as the Courier's.

Armor degrades based on damage taken.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the post the comment was made on, I suspected that this was possible, but couldn't prove it. However, I think I found evidence that it happens just now, at least on Hardcore mode/Very Hard difficulty.

I gave my companion a Super Sledge and got into a fight with several Legionaries, who typically carry machetes and magnums. I didn't see any with Super Sledges, though it was nighttime in-game and I could have just missed it. Sometime during the battle, I heard my companion yell "I'm gonna need a new weapon!" When the fight was over, I went back to the spot where my companion had been. She was back to carrying her default weapon, and I found a Super Sledge on the ground with an empty CND gauge. Oddly, its hover text was red, but I didn't suffer a karma penalty for picking it up.

I was able to put the broken weapon back in her inventory, proving my assumption in the previous post wrong. She wasn't able to equip it, but I was able to take it back out of her inventory later to transfer it to a container.

Comment: the question now is, was the SS damaged because it was used or because it got hit during the fight?

Comment: @Xantec, indeed. It was at about 50%, so I'm surprised it would fail for _any_ reason. Not sure how to come up with a test for that.

Comment: without seeing the code i'm not sure any test would be 100% conclusive. you could try making a test ESM with the GECK. create a ittle building that inside continuously spawns Legionaries. but even then it would be hard to know what was happening with everyone running around.

Answer (score 1):

I gave chainsaw to Veronica and when we fought some ghouls she broke it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I gave the Plasma Caster to Cass, and she rendered it useless within a few hours of gameplay. Costed a bomb to repair it.